# Too much space between appbar and page content in react-native using native base 3.2.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, native-base

I created a custom app-bar using native base 3.2.0, and react-navigation 6.x but there[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf6Pc.png) is too much gap between the screen content and app-bar.

This is my Custom Header file code

```
  import React from 'react';
import {
  HStack,
  NativeBaseProvider,
  Icon,
  IconButton,
  Text,
  Box,
  StatusBar,
} from 'native-base';
import MatIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const CustomHeader = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="red" barStyle="light-content" />
      <Box safeAreaTop backgroundColor="#6200ee">
        <HStack
          bg="#6200ee"
          px="1"
          py="1"
          justifyContent="space-between"
          alignItems="center">
          <HStack space="4" alignItems="center">
            <IconButton
              icon={
                <Icon
                  size="sm"
                  as={<MatIcon name="account-circle" />}
                  color="white"
                />
              }
            />
            <Text color="white" fontSize="20" fontWeight="bold">
              Home Page
            </Text>
          </HStack>
          <HStack space="2" px="1" py="1">
            <IconButton
              icon={
                <Icon size="sm" as={<MatIcon name="search" />} color="white" />
              }
            />
          </HStack>
        </HStack>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <CustomHeader />
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};
```

This is my App.js file code

```
  const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          header: () => <CustomHeader />,
        }}
        initialRouteName="Home"
        >
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

what can I do to remove the gap between the header and the page content.

Comment: can you explain your image ?? what appbar?

Comment: The blue portion is the appbar and there is too much gap between appbar and the place where the text from the home component is rendered. I don't want the extra space

Comment: please try to step by step debugging to find the solution. start with commenting on the code parts to check the abnormal behaviors with extra spaces. as a guess, another header component is still in your codes that provide these extra spaces. take a look at the NativeBaseProvider elements which may have a default padding or margin in it.